# Alternative to Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: search-engine

I have a few Google CSE that let me search a number of sites and subdomains for news articles. I would prefer to not use Google and instead use something like DuckDuckGo, but is there any other software that offers a similar functionality?

My workflow is to add the approved sites in advance, blacklist any undesired sections of the sites (such as forums on the site, by directory name), and then to simply search using a phrase at a specific address.